# Javascript syntax error on my website

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.star').mouseover(function (){
var star = $(this).index() 1;
$(this).parent().css("background-position","0 -" (32 * star) "px");
});

$('.star-rating').mouseout(function (){
var originalresult = $(this).attr('id').split('result')[1];
$(this).css("background-position","0 -" (32 * originalresult) "px");
});
</script>

<div class="star-rating" id="rating1result0">
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
</div>
<div class="result">
<span style="color:green">0</span> (0)
</div>
```

I get these 2 error messages:

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```
$(this).parent().css("background-position","0 -" (32 * star) "px");
```

and 
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

```
var star = $(this).index() 1;
```

Comment: Looks like you don't like plus `+` operator.

Comment: You're not string-concatenating with `+`. Plus, why is `1` all lonely next to `.index()`? Kinda sad to see it left out like that.

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 4):

```
("background-position","0 -" (32 * star) "px"
                            X           X
```

The error message is slightly misleading. It is looking for a `)` to match the one at the start of the code I quoted. If you were to add one you would just get a different error. The problem is that you need an operator at the two places marked `X`.

You are probably looking for a `+` (although others would be syntactically valid, albeit less useful in the context)

```
var star = $(this).index() 1;
```

You have a similar problem here. Again, it looks like you want to add `1` to the index.

Comment: We've been oppressed by those scurrilous `+`. I'll show them *operator*. Ha. Ha.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I don't get any error's anymore but it's still not working. And I know my server supports javascript, but this is actually ajax code.. Is it included in the code the right way?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you have to use the + as concat operator.

http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/operators/string-operator.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.star').mouseover(function (){
    var star = $(this).index() + 1;
    $(this).parent().css("background-position","0 -" + (32 * star) + "px");
});

$('.star-rating').mouseout(function (){
    var originalresult = $(this).attr('id').split('result')[1];
    $(this).css("background-position","0 -" + (32 * originalresult) + "px");
});
</script>

<div class="star-rating" id="rating1result0">
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
</div>
<div class="result">
<span style="color:green">0</span> (0)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce Concatenation Operator `+` so here is correct lines of codes:

```
var star = $(this).index() + 1;
$(this).parent().css("background-position","0 -" +(32 * star)+ "px");
$(this).css("background-position","0 -" +(32 * originalresult) +"px");
```

try this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.star').mouseover(function (){
var star = $(this).index() + 1;
$(this).parent().css("background-position","0 -" +(32 * star)+ "px");
});

$('.star-rating').mouseout(function (){
var originalresult = $(this).attr('id').split('result')[1];
$(this).css("background-position","0 -" +(32 * originalresult) +"px");
});
</script>

<div class="star-rating" id="rating1result0">
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
</div>
<div class="result">
<span style="color:green">0</span> (0)
</div>
```